# Incorrect Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, 20.04, kernel

I bought a new laptop which had Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled but since it also had some unnecessary programs I downloaded the newest version from the official website, created a bootable flash drive and reinstalled the OS on the laptop(when I did that I had to restart it a couple of times since there was a kernel error when I tried to select UBUNTU in the boot menu). I chose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" since I wanted a clean SSD and normal installation. After installing the OS the laptop doesn't turn on with the first attempt(I have to select "Ubuntu" from the boot menu and it shows some kernel errors), there is an installed undeletable Core 18 application and the worst thing: when I wake the laptop up from sleep mode it just shows a black screen. I have an Nvidia graphics card but the solutions for the last problem from other questions here (change grub file) did nothing. At this moment I definitely think I made a mistake somewhere so is there something I can do to fix this? My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 5593 with Intel Core i7 1065G7 CPU and nVidia GeForce MX230 graphics card.

Comment: What kind of computer are you installing Ubuntu on? With a bit more info we might be able to help out.

Comment: Next time try just uninstalling the "unnecessary programs".